# Process Failing with Result: Failed to update records that meet the filter criteria

Tags: process-builder, automation

I'm getting the following error emailed to me for a process that is failing. I think its failing on the first scheduled action: 'Update Auth' but I can't figure out why. I was thinking there were lookup filters on the field its updating but I checked and there are none. Please help!

```
Error element myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0_SA1 (FlowRecordUpdate).
The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “Surgery Confirmation Process - Authorization” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients Error ID: 1381761422-161107 (-2001240630)Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients Error ID: 1381761422-161107 (-2001240630). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
Flow Details
Flow API Name: Surgery_Confirmation_Process
Type: Record Change Process
Version: 3
Status: Active
Org: Pearl Precision Surgery (00Df40000047Nef)
Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: Surgery_Confirmation_Process-3_InterviewLabel
Current User: Justin Pearce (005f40000039VBF)
Start time: 9/30/2021 6:22 PM
Duration: 100 seconds
How the Interview Started
Justin Pearce (005f40000039VBF) started the flow interview.
API Version for Running the Flow: 49
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
myVariable_old = Case (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
myVariable_current = Case (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
DECISION: myPreWaitDecision_myWait_myRule_1
Outcome executed: myPreWaitRule_myWait_myRule_1
Outcome conditions:
{!myVariable_current.Ready_to_Confirm__c} (true) Equals true
DECISION: myDecision
Outcome executed: myRule_1
Outcome conditions:
{!myVariable_current.Ready_to_Confirm__c} (true) Equals true
DECISION: myRule_1_pmetdec
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: myRule_1_pmetnullrule
Outcome conditions:
{!myVariable_old} (Case (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)) Is null true

Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: myRule_1_pmetrule
Outcome conditions:
{!myVariable_old.Ready_to_Confirm__c} (false) Equals true

Default outcome executed.
CREATE RECORDS: myRule_1_A1
Create one tdc_tsw__Scheduled_Sms__c record where:
Name = {!myVariable_current.Id} (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
tdc_tsw__Phone_Api__c = {!myVariable_current.Phone__c} (602-909-9267)
tdc_tsw__Related_Object_Id__c = {!myVariable_current.Id} (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
tdc_tsw__SMS_Template__c = a1Xf4000003EF2LEAW
Result
A record is ready to be created when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishes.
UPDATE RECORDS: myRule_1_A2
Find all Case_Application__c records where:
Surgery__c Equals {!myVariable_current.Id} (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
Update the records’ field values.
Surgery_Confirmed__c = true
Result
All records that meet the filter criteria are ready to be updated when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishes.
UPDATE RECORDS: myRule_1_A3
Find all Case records where:
Id Equals {!myVariable_current.Id} (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
Update the records’ field values.
Surgery_Scheduled_Date__c = {!formula_2_myRule_1_A3_6927492698} (September 30, 2021)
Result
All records that meet the filter criteria are ready to be updated when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishes.
PAUSE: myWait_myRule_1
The pause conditions were met for these pause configurations:
Pause Configuration: myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0
Pause conditions:
{!myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0_postActionExecutionVariable} (false) Equals false

Resume event type: Alarm: Absolute Time
Base Time = {!$Flow.InterviewStartTime} (9/30/2021 6:22 PM)
Offset Unit = Hours
Offset Number = 0
Pause Configuration: myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1
Pause conditions:
{!myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1_postActionExecutionVariable} (false) Equals false

Resume event type: Alarm: Relative Time
Object Type = Case
Record ID = {!myVariable_current.Id} (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
Offset Unit = Hours
Offset Number = -7
Base Date/Time Field = Surgery_Date__c
Result
Paused at 9/30/2021 6:22 PM.
The interview was paused at 9/30/2021 6:22 PM.
Transaction Committed
Any records that the flow was ready to create, update, or delete were committed to the database.
The interview was resumed at 9/30/2021 6:23 PM by Justin Pearce (005f40000039VBF).
PAUSE: myWait_myRule_1
The resume event occurred for the myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1 pause configuration.
The following values from the resume event were stored in these flow variables:
None.
DECISION: myPostWaitDecision_myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1
Outcome executed: myPostWaitRule_myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1
Outcome conditions:
{!myVariable_current.Surgery_Date__c} (8/26/2021 10:00 AM) Is null false
CREATE RECORDS: myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1_SA1
Create one tdc_tsw__Scheduled_Sms__c record where:
Name = {!myVariable_current.Id} (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
tdc_tsw__Phone_Api__c = {!myVariable_current.Phone__c} (602-909-9267)
tdc_tsw__Question__c = a1cf4000004MLnEAAW
tdc_tsw__Related_Object_Id__c = {!myVariable_current.Id} (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
Result
A record is ready to be created when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishes.
ASSIGNMENT: myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1_postWaitExecutionAssignment
{!myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1_postActionExecutionVariable} Equals true
Result
{!myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_1_postActionExecutionVariable} = "true"
PAUSE: myWait_myRule_1
The pause conditions were met for these pause configurations:
Pause Configuration: myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0
Pause conditions:
{!myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0_postActionExecutionVariable} (false) Equals false

Resume event type: Alarm: Absolute Time
Base Time = {!$Flow.InterviewStartTime} (9/30/2021 6:22 PM)
Offset Unit = Hours
Offset Number = 0
Result
Paused at 9/30/2021 6:23 PM.
The interview was paused at 9/30/2021 6:23 PM.
Transaction Committed
Any records that the flow was ready to create, update, or delete were committed to the database.
The interview was resumed at 9/30/2021 6:24 PM by Justin Pearce (005f40000039VBF).
PAUSE: myWait_myRule_1
The resume event occurred for the myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0 pause configuration.
The following values from the resume event were stored in these flow variables:
None.
UPDATE RECORDS: myWaitEvent_myWait_myRule_1_event_0_SA1
Find all Case_Presentation_for_Authorization__c records where:
Surgery__c Equals {!myVariable_current.Id} (5005G00000ne1LOQAY)
Update the records’ field values.
Surgery_Confirmed__c = true
Result
Failed to update records that meet the filter criteria.
Error Occurred: The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “Surgery Confirmation Process - Authorization” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients Error ID: 1381761422-161107 (-2001240630)Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients Error ID: 1381761422-161107 (-2001240630). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
Salesforce Error ID: 1381761422-161111 (930626253)
```

[image: Process that is failing]

Comment: See: [What is a Gack?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack) You need to open a case with Salesforce support.

Comment: Your scheduled action is based on `Case` yet the Process Builder target object is a `Surgery`.  Scheduled actions need to be on the same target object

Comment: Thanks. So I tried removing the Update Auth step as a scheduled action and adding it to the immediate action step and now I get the following error when trying to save a record:

Comment: Review the errors on this page.
We can't save this record because the “Surgery Confirmation Process” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “Surgery Confirmation Process - Authorization” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients Error ID: 1715909953-201569 (1430921330)Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients Error ID: 1715909953-

Comment: 201569 (1430921330). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 1715909953-201570 (2024426658)k up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 1715909953-201570 (2024426658)